# Making bootstrap dropdown transparent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I need to get the bootstrap dropdown transparent. How can this be achieved. Below is the html

```
<div id="mydiv" class="dropdown transparentbar" style="z-index:4">
       <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="mybyn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
         Drop mat
         <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
```

CSS

```
     .transparentbar {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        cursor:pointer;
        outline:none;
        border:none;
        box-shadow:none; 
        background-image: none;

        background-color: transparent;
        background: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;

    }
```

Can you please help?

Comment: What CSS do you have? Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: CSS that I have tried attached. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear *which* part is supposed to be transparent so I'm going to assume it's **not** the button but rather the actual list that appears on click.

The background color is controlled by this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff; /* here */
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

**So I would recommend being slightly more specific in the selector to avoid affecting any other dropdowns**

```
#mydiv > .dropdown-menu {
    background:transparent;
}
```

**EDIT: The button is controlled by the `btn-default` class**

```
#mydiv > btn-default {
    background:transparent;
}
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body {
  background:pink !important;
}

#mydiv > .btn-default {
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mydiv" class="dropdown transparentbar" style="z-index:4">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="mybyn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Drop mat
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

[**Bootply Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/EeVqbJj7R2)

Comment: Its the button that needs to be transparent; sorry i did not made it clear at first

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Bootstrap 3.3.6 and using it's LESS variable system, You can do the following to control the color hue,and level of transparency, all in one shot...

```
@dropdown-bg:rgba(248,248,248,.90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try this way?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  body {background-color: #999;}
  .dropdown-menu {background-color: transparent;}
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```