# how to make the dropdown menu transparent with only visible item to be the arrow inside the button and the right border?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

here i need the dropdown button to be transparent but if i do `background:transparent;` only visible thing is the border, i need it to be the arrow icon that appears inside the dropdown button and the right border.
here is the code

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Regular</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
<< This is what I need it to be

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445171/making-bootstrap-dropdown-transparent

Comment: I can't see any arrow icon in your code.

Is the arrow maybe a background image on the button?
That could be why it dissappears, when removing the background. Try using "background-color: transparent;" instead.

It would be a great help if you could do a fiddle or codepen to show your full example.

Comment: by arrown icon i mean the arrow that appears in the button when you make it a dropdown menu button

Comment: For the border can i just put the dropdown button and give the div a right border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  background:transparent;
  color: black;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Regular</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here with bootstrap: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGZNKd

The arrow is white, so when you make the background transparent, if the background behind that is also white you can't see it. So I made it black to make it visible.

Note: this css selector will change all dropdown buttons so you'll probably want to make it more specific.

Edit: updated to show the right border.

Comment: thankyou i did make it so that the button is transparent but now how do i make it so as only the right border appears

Comment: updated. can't really tell what the border looks like in your screenshot, but the update shows the right border of the button. you can change the color with css